# python-markdown doesn't recognize code block?

Tags: python, markdown

I'm working on a script to transfer `Markdown` to HTML, I've tried both `markdown` and `markdown2`.
As I use `MathJax` to make it able to show math formulas in LaTex, I found `markdown` is better for me than `markdown2`.
However, both of them don't recognize code blocks in ```` ``` ````.
My code is written in `Python`.

My `Markdown` code is:

````
计算香农熵的函数：

```

from math import log

def calcShannonEnt(dataSet):
   numEntries = len(dataSet) #类别个数
   labelCount = {}
   for featVec in dataSet: #对每一条数据
       currentLabel = featVec[-1] #currentLabel为当前数据的类别
       if currentLabel not in labelCount.keys(): #计数
           labelCount[currentLabel] = 0
       labelCount[currentLabel] += 1
   shannonEnt = 0.0
   for key in labelCount.keys():
       prob = float(labelCount[key]) / float(numEntries)
       shannonEnt -= prob * float(log(prob,2))#计算香农熵
   return shannonEnt

```


使用要求：

- 调用的数据必须储存在列表中，且所有列表元素有相同长度
- 列表元素的最后一列为类别

[sorted函数及operator.itemgetter函数的用法详解](http://blog.csdn.net/alvine008/article/details/37757753
````

I hope those Chinese characters don't bother you.
The HTML code is :

````
<p>计算香农熵的函数：</p>
<pre><code>```

from math import log

def calcShannonEnt(dataSet):
   numEntries = len(dataSet) #类别个数
   labelCount = {}
   for featVec in dataSet: #对每一条数据
       currentLabel = featVec[-1] #currentLabel为当前数据的类别
       if currentLabel not in labelCount.keys(): #计数
           labelCount[currentLabel] = 0
       labelCount[currentLabel] += 1
   shannonEnt = 0.0
   for key in labelCount.keys():
       prob = float(labelCount[key]) / float(numEntries)
       shannonEnt -= prob * float(log(prob,2))#计算香农熵
   return shannonEnt

```


使用要求：

- 调用的数据必须储存在列表中，且所有列表元素有相同长度
- 列表元素的最后一列为类别

[sorted函数及operator.itemgetter函数的用法详解](http://blog.csdn.net/alvine008/article/details/37757753
</code></pre>
````

What's the problem?

Comment: Did you enable the [extension](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/fenced_code_blocks.html)? It is not enabled by default as fenced code blocks are not a standard Markdown feature. Perhaps some code showing how you called Python-Markdown would provide us with something we can help you with.

Comment: Yeah. It is because of the extension. I've solved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

With the help of @Waylan the problem has been solved perfectly.
It is because I didn't enable the extensions. See [extensions](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/index.html)

Now it is right:

```
html_txt = markdown.markdown(post.body_markdown, extensions=['fenced_code'])
```

Comment: If you are interested in command line: these lines worked: ___ python3 -m markdown -x fenced_code psql.md > psql.html ___ and ___ markdown_py -x fenced_code psql.md > psql.html